# Server admin community on a blog platform?

Tags: website, windows

I'm wondering if there is a site out there where server admins congregate and post useful bits and pieces. Server Fault for example is a great Q&A site and Slashdot Journal Entries could be useful if I was more a PFY than BOFH ;)

The reason for my thought is that I have been writing some powershell scripts for doing bulk administration of iLO interfaces that seems to work nicely, and I think there would be others who would like these scripts. I am thinking about a blog format so I can annotate, etc.

I don't really think a script repository site is the most useful - I don't go looking for script repositories in google, I google for what I am after. Also, ideally, I don't want to have to maintain my own blog and build an audience - I'd rather fit in with a group of other admins.

Does anyone know if such a site exists? If not, I might just have to scare everyone with my exceptional use of iWeb :)

Comment: I too was wondering the same thing

Comment: this could make a great business model :) ..and *shouldn't* be horribly hard to implement ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people have a blog, and publish their snippets there.  They congregate by having their blogs published on systems administration planets, which you can keep up with via a newsreader.  They communicate as a community using trackbacks, openid, etc.

Comment: +1 for the sysadmin planets. There are several great (very prolific and verbose) sysadmin bloggers on planet sysadmin. Ive found it a great resource for seeing what others are doing and see what best practices they have developed for their systems.

Comment: Yep, I think I am finding that this is the way to go - to keep my own dodgy blog, and get it linked into an aggregator :) Thanks to everyone for their insights.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me to be just looking for a good SysAdmin related forum, no? There are several that come to my mind, but really I think your best bet would be to blog those things and then disperse links to those blog posts. Blogging allows for a semi-permament document to be posted, edited, added to, commented on and shared with everyone on the interwebs. You don't really have to maintain it any more than you want to and you also need not build an audience. Just keep it around as a personal, public documentation effort and those things that are Google worthy will get picked up. Self-reference your blog if a question on a forum comes up, give the link out to friends, etc. and you might be surprised at how an audience can grow without you really trying. Maybe the PlanetSysAdmin blogroll would pick you up and then your desire for Utopian information exchange would be fulfilled...

...at least until you get flamed for using PowerShell over Python, or some such silliness. =)

Or maybe you could post it to [this SysAdmin Wiki](http://sysadmin.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page)? On second thought, that might not be the best fit. Maybe some of us could band together and create our own SysAdmin site using Wiki software but populating it with more nuts and bolts scripts, how-tos, hacks and whatnot rather than encyclopedic entries.

Or not. =)